# How do i link to my Image-Folder inside my Apache Wicket Application?

Tags: java, image, apache, wicket, contextpath

My Package-Structure looks like:

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/test/java
- src/test/resources
- src/main/webapp/css
- src/main/webapp/images
- src/main/js
- src/main/WEB-INF

My images are stored under src/main/webapp/images.

Now i want to dynamically link to a picture e.g.:

```
    Image picture = new Image("picture",
                    new ContextRelativeResource("/images/races/"
                            + dynamicPicture));
```

The Problem is, that my Application can't find /images/races/$dynamicPicture.
How do i set the correct path to my image folder? The Appliation Server used is Jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work with (removed the leading slash)

```
    Image picture = new Image("picture",
                new ContextRelativeResource("images/races/"
                        + dynamicPicture));
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your code should work. Are you using Maven to manage your project and to start Jetty?

Comment: I use maven to manage my project. To deploy my project, i run "Run as -> Maven Install". Then i copy the .war File to my webapps Folder in the Jetty Directory.

Comment: Now i copied all the images into the specific package of my Java-Class and .html file and implemented the image with:  new Image("image",
      new PackageResourceReference(MyPage.class,
        picture + ".gif"));
It's not what i wanted but it works.

Comment: Try by removing the leading slash from "/images/races". I also think that it should work. You can simplify it a bit by using ContextImage component.

Comment: @martin-g How can this be the solution? ContextRelativeResource checks whether there's a leading slash and adds one if it's omitted (1.5.7).